# What is AdMob Default ID?

Tags: admob, mopub

I want to show admob ad by mobup. So i have created network in mopub. So i have a problem who know what is AdMob Default ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default AdMob publisher ID. You'll need to go to sign up for an AdMob account at [admob.com](http://www.admob.com), and then create a site/app to get a publisher ID. Then hook that ID up with Mopub's mediation platform.

Answer (score 0):

Sign into admob. 
You must have created an app. 
Click on 'Site & apps' tab. 
Then find app and click on 'Manage settings'. 
Publisher ID is on the top left of the page.

Cheers,
Elaine www.thechocolatelabapps.com